# Changing "on-hold" reason in reopen review task

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen

While reviewing "on hold" questions for re-opening, I encountered several times the case where a question was put on hold for "Off topic - question does not demonstrate minimal understanding...". As a result the OP edited the question and practically dumped his entire  code there.

Now there is a **minimal** understanding of the subject but it's no no longer SSCCE.

Is it possible to have an option in "leave closed" but with a changed reason?

Comment: No, just comment on the post to explain the question is still off-topic.